# How to output memory usage profiled by Diagnostic Tools?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2017, memory-consumption

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 provides [**Diagnostic Tools**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage).
Using this tool, we can read the memory used at anytime during a program is running, which is very helpful.
However, this reading has to be manually.

The original problem I want to solve is [to get the peak memory usage for each instance in a single process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210685/how-to-get-the-peak-memory-usage-peakworkingset64-for-each-instance-in-a-singl).
If I can output, from Diagnostic Tools, the **memory usage** together with the time, then I can write a program to find the peak memory usage during a time interval, where each time interval is recorded for solving an instance.

I understand that the memory measured by Diagnostic Tools is actually [`PeakPagedMemorySize64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakpagedmemorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx) of class [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx), while I really want to know is the value of [`PeakWorkingSet64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64(v=vs.110).aspx). Nevertheless, this is acceptable because the two values are quite close (for an instance, `PeakPagedMemorySize64 = 1,272,377,344 bytes` and `PeakWorkingSet64 = 1,225,867,264 bytes`).

Comment: That's the job of the performance analysis tools in Visual Studio. The Diagnostics window displays a simplified performance analysis view that's only available during debugging. You *can* find the memory used by each type in Diagnostic tools as well, if you wake a memory snapshot in the Memory tab

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can I wake a memory snapshot by my program? I would like to snapshot every second.

Comment: No, but the diagnostic tools are meant as an *easy* way to profile. The profiling tools are far more powerful and can either instrument the code capturing every allocation or sample and take snapshots.

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve though? For example, you could use a library like [logary](https://github.com/logary/logary) to record multiple perf metrics on a schedule. That's far more appropriate for monitoring eg a production release. Application Insights work in a similar manner but send their metrics to Azure. Or perhaps you should look for GCs, not peak memory. If your application generates a lot of temporary objects and strings, you'll see a sawtooth shape even in the Diagnostic Tools, that drops each time a GC is executed

Comment: I want to know how much memory my program needs to solve an instance (I have 734 instances in total). My program uses a function from library ILOG.CPLEX.dll to solve an integer linear program. This library is a black box for me so I can't use GCs inside the library. From the Diagnostics window, I can see how much memory my program uses, but I want to know the memory usage for each of the 734 instances. This is why I want to make snapshot every second automatically.

Comment: Then logary or manually reading and loggint perf counters is a better solution. A quick& dirty solution would be to start Performance Monitor and add the .NET, Process counters that correspond to your process instance. There are a *lot* of counters you can use, including GCs, allocations, objects on the .NET side, working set, private bytes, rates etc on the `Process` category. You can configure perf mon to log those counters to a file periodically

Comment: A *very* dirty solution is to add entire categories of counters, filter them by the process instance and store them to a file.